# Wifi networks not detected by Lubuntu

Tags: networking, lubuntu, network-manager, essid

Yesterday I wanted to connect to a wifi network. The "network" icon in the bottom bar was a square and nothing happened when I clicked on it. In "Preferences" I found "Advanced network configuration". I clicked the '+' sign at the bottom and selected "wifi".

Then I was asked the SSID. On the next tab, I had to choose the "security". The person who was running the place told me the password, and then the name of the network. But he didn't know what type of security it had. Turned out to be wpa2. Now it functions, but the same problem will happen in the next place I visit with this computer...

I would like to see right away the names of the available networks. Then I could select one, enter the password (if any) and be done. I used to have wifi-radar, but this doesn't seem available on lubuntu. Nor is wicd. I installed gnome-system-tools and nothing. No new option in "Internet", "System tools" or "Preferences". I typed :

```
sudo apt-cache search network-admin
gnome-system-tools - Cross-platform configuration utilities
sudo network-admin
command not found
```

What tool am I supposed to use under lubuntu, please?

Comment: You've not provided release details; so I'll provide the URL for the manual for the *latest* stable release or 21.10 (2021-October release) - https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/   Lubuntu uses LXQt and not GNOME, and click on it?  (left-click? or right click? as they each have different functions - please be specific).